# Check occurences using regex

Tags: regex

I search for a regex expression that should be either:

- BILL followed by 10 digits ( the total length should be 14 )
- AAAASPA followed by 6 digits ( the total length should be 13 )

I tried this `^(BILL\d{10}){14}|(AAAASPA\d{6}){13}$`

But It does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `(BILL\d{10}){14}` matches `BILL` + 10 digits after it 14 times. This `{14}`  quantifier is redundant here, since the length limit is set by the preceding pattern itself.

Also, the anchors are only applied *separately* to the alternatives, the first will only match at the start of string, and the other will match at the end of string.

You need to use

```
^(BILL\d{10}|AAAASPA\d{6})$
```

Or

```
^(?:BILL\d{10}|AAAASPA\d{6})$
```

If your regex flavor does not support `\d`, use `[0-9]`.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/gPVrfw/1).

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `(` - start of a grouping construct (`(?:...)` is a non-capturing group, not supported by POSIX regex flavor)

  - `BILL\d{10}`  - `BILL` string and then ten digits
  - `|` - or
  - `AAAASPA\d{6}` - `AAAASPA` string and then six digits
- `)` - end of the grouping
- `$` - end of string.

Note the grouping here that ensures proper anchoring.